# ld ignores libraries

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, ld

The linker in Ubuntu 11.10 seems to ignore libraries I specified on the link line if they do not contain any symbols used by the linked application:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/gpu_sd_list
cd /home/eile/Software/gpu-sd/debug/apps/gpu_sd_list && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/gpu_sd_list.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -Wall -Wextra -Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wsign-promo -Wshadow -Winit-self -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-write-strings -Werror -g    CMakeFiles/gpu_sd_list.dir/gpu_sd_list.cpp.o  -o ../../bin/gpu_sd_list -rdynamic ../../lib/libgpusd_remote_dns_sd.so.1.0.0 -ldns_sd ../../lib/libgpusd_remote.so.1.0.0 -Wl,-rpath,/home/eile/Software/gpu-sd/debug/lib: 

ldd ./debug/bin/gpu_sd_list
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff0a5c6000)
libgpusd_remote.so.1 => /home/eile/Software/gpu-sd/debug/lib/libgpusd_remote.so.1 (0x00007ff9a21fc000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff9a1ece000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff9a1cb7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff9a1918000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff9a1694000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff9a2406000)
```

libgpusd_remote_dns_sd.so.1.0.0 is missing. This works in Ubuntu 11.04. The library contains a static initializer registering a module with the gpusd_remote library. If it is not loaded at program launch functionality is missing. The full source is at https://github.com/Eyescale/gpu-sd

Comment: Can you explicitly reference (from your code) this initializer in some way?

Comment: The idea is that users of this library can decide which modules they need by simply linking them to their application.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
.... -Wl,-no-as-needed -lfoo -lbar -Wl,-as-needed
```

This will link against `libfoo` and `libbar` regardless of whether they are actually needed or not.

`as-needed` is a default setting on some distributions, since it makes sense in most cases.

(I'm not sure your design is a good idea though.)

Comment: Thanks, adding 'set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,--no-as-needed")' to my CMakeLists.txt solved the issue.

Comment: Re design: the library has different modules to query which GPU's are available, e.g., AGL and GLX. Each has its own dependencies. The application can then choose which one to use, and what other DSOs are sucked in. Do you have a suggestion on how to achieve this better?

Comment: A normal lib with an `initFooBar(params)` method that loads the appropriate "real" libraries at runtime an does whatever initialization is needed. That's a pretty common "plugin" approach.

Comment: Sure, this requires the base lib to know all the plugins beforehand. I'll think about it - thanks.

Comment: It doesn't. The base lib can process configuration files and/or env. vars for example.